# Why do I get the error TronWeb is not a constructor?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Can you tell me why I get the error:

> tronweb_1.TronWeb is not a constructor?

trc.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { TronWeb } from "tronweb";

@Injectable()
export class TrcService {
  tronWebCall() {
    return new TronWeb({ // error here //
      fullHost: 'https://api.trongrid.io',
      headers: { 'TRON-PRO-API-KEY': process.env.TRONGRID_API_KEY },
    });
  }

  async createAccount(request) {
    try {
      const tronWeb = this.tronWebCall();
      const response = await tronWeb.createAccount();

      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }
}
```

Framework: NestJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is because of the way you're importing that package. Try:
`import * as TronWeb from "tronweb";`

That's not related to nestjs btw but typescript, see: [`esModuleInterop`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop)